# What is this duaa for?

Tags: dua

[image]

Does anyone know what this duaa is for?

Answer (score 2):

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said "**The most superior way of asking for forgiveness from Allah is:** 'Allahumma anta Rabbi la ilaha illa anta, Khalaqtani wa ana 'Abduka, wa ana 'ala 'ahdika wa wa'dika mastata'tu, A'udhu bika min Sharri ma sana'tu, abu'u Laka bini`matika 'alaiya, wa abu'u laka bidhanbi faghfir lee fa innahu la yaghfiru adhdhunuba illa anta." The Prophet (ﷺ) added. "**If somebody recites it during the day with firm faith in it, and dies on the same day before the evening, he will be from the people of Paradise; and if somebody recites it at night with firm faith in it, and dies before the morning, he will be from the people of Paradise.**"

REFERENCE:
Sahih al-Bukhari 6306
https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6306

Comment: Jazakallah khair